# User Types In Django using the same login and registration form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I've been hitting my head for the best way to implement this. I want to create two user type in my django site: Free and Premium users. Both users will register through the same registration form and login through the same login form. But will be able to view different content. Do you think @user_passes_test will be the best for this? Or what is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something like this before. I utilized Django's [contrib.auth groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#groups) system for this. You can create [arbitrary permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions) and then assign them to the various groups. You can then test to see if a given user has permissions for various actions. The [permission required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator) is useful for this.

Comment: All the links are broken.